# Android ANR Multithreading

Tags: android, multithreading

So I'm working on a project which needs to cut up a video into multiple frames, and save them as Bitmaps on the device.

I'm using `FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime()` to obtain the individual frames, which is working, but is slow. To speed it up a bit I'm trying to implement multiple worker threads which go off and grab the frames, finally responding back to UI via an anonymous function.

I have a class `MyVideoProcessor` which handles the video processing, and this is called from my `EditVideoActivity`.

The threads start, and start processing, but shortly afterwards the `EditVideoActivity` dies (ANR).

From what I can see, there is nothing running on UI (apart from at the very end (which I confirm only runs once)) so not sure why the UI thread is being held up by the worker threads.

**EDIT**:
So I've switched out `FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever` for the standard MediaMetadataRetriever and everything works. BUT I need to use `FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever`, as the OPTION_CLOSEST in MMR doesn't work as it should.

**EditVideoActivity:**

```
    if (mBackgroundThread==null || !mBackgroundThread.isAlive()) {
        mBackgroundThread = new Thread(mMyVideoProcessor);
        mBackgroundThread.start();
    }
```

**MyVideoProcessor:**

```
public class MyVideoProcessor implements Runnable {

    private static final String TAG = MyVideoProcessor.class.getSimpleName();

    private MyVideo mMyVideo;
    private final Context mContext;
    public static final int FRAME_CUT_DURATION = 200;
    private int mStartFrom = 0;
    private int mCurrentDuration = 0;
    private int mVideoDuration = 0;
    private ArrayList<OnFrameUpdateListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    private ExecutorService mProcessors = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

    public MyVideoProcessor(Context context, MyVideo myVideo) {
        mContext = context;
        mMyVideo = myVideo;
    }

    public void setOnFrameUpdateListener(OnFrameUpdateListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public int getCurrentDuration() {
        return mCurrentDuration;
    }

    public void setStartFrom(int startFrom) {
        mStartFrom = startFrom;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (!mMyVideo.getProcessed()) {
            FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
            retriever.setDataSource(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + mMyVideo.getVideo());
            String time = retriever.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
            retriever.release();
            mVideoDuration = Integer.parseInt(time);

            int i = 0;
            if (mStartFrom > 0) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Attempting restore");
                i = mStartFrom+1;
            }

            for ( i=i;i<mVideoDuration;i+=FRAME_CUT_DURATION) {
                mProcessors.execute(new ExtractImageExecutor(i));
            }
        }
    }

    public class ExtractImageExecutor implements Runnable {

        private int mTime;

        public ExtractImageExecutor(int time) {
            mTime = time;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
            retriever.setDataSource(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + mMyVideo.getVideo());

            mCurrentDuration = mTime;
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Bitmap bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(mTime*1000, FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.d(TAG, "Took: " + ((endTime - startTime) / 1000f));

            if (bitmap != null) {

                try {
                    int thisFrame = 0;
                    if (mTime>0) {
                        thisFrame = mTime/FRAME_CUT_DURATION;
                    }

                    //noinspection StringBufferReplaceableByString
                    StringBuilder frameFilename = new StringBuilder();
                    frameFilename.append("VIDEO_");
                    frameFilename.append(thisFrame).append("_");
                    frameFilename.append(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm", Locale.UK).format(new Date()));
                    frameFilename.append(".jpg");

                    File frameFile = new File(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null), frameFilename.toString());
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(frameFile);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
                    fos.close();
                    mMyVideo.addFrame(thisFrame, frameFile);
                    /*for (OnFrameUpdateListener listener : listeners) {
                        listener.onFrameUpdate(mMyVideo);
                    }*/
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            retriever.release();

            if ((mTime+FRAME_CUT_DURATION) > mVideoDuration) {
                mMyVideo.setProcessed(true);
                for (OnFrameUpdateListener listener : listeners) {
                    listener.onFrameUpdate(mMyVideo);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EditVideoActivity:**

```
public class EditVideoActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = EditVideoActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ImageView mImageView;

    private MyVideo mMyVideo;
    private MyVideoProcessor mMyVideoProcessor;
    private Thread mBackgroundThread;
    private int mCurrentDuration = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_video);
        String videoFilename = getIntent().getStringExtra("videoFilename");
        if (videoFilename != null) {
            mMyVideo = new MyVideo(MyVideo.TYPE_EXTERIOR,"TEST",new File(videoFilename));
            mMyVideoProcessor = new MyVideoProcessor(this,mMyVideo);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "There was a problem with the video file");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Saving Instance State");
        outState.putParcelable("video", mMyVideo);
        outState.putInt("currentDuration", mMyVideoProcessor.getCurrentDuration());
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Restoring Instance State");
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mMyVideo = (MyVideo) savedInstanceState.getParcelable("video");
        mCurrentDuration = savedInstanceState.getInt("currentDuration");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mMyVideoProcessor = new MyVideoProcessor(this,mMyVideo);

        final TextView totalFrames    = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalFrames);
        mImageView                    = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        final SeekBar seekBar         = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        progressBar.animate();
        seekBar.setEnabled(false);

        OnFrameUpdateListener onFrameUpdateListener = new OnFrameUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFrameUpdate(final MyVideo myVideo) {
                if (myVideo.getProcessed()) {
                    File lastFrame = myVideo.getLastFrame();
                    totalFrames.setText(myVideo.getTotalFrames()+"");
                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(lastFrame.getAbsolutePath()));
                    seekBar.setEnabled(true);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        };

        mMyVideoProcessor.setOnFrameUpdateListener(onFrameUpdateListener);
        if (mBackgroundThread==null || !mBackgroundThread.isAlive()) {
            mBackgroundThread = new Thread(mMyVideoProcessor);
            mBackgroundThread.start();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Show us `EditVideoActivity` code.

Comment: I prefer using AsynTask instead of Thread.