# FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime() is slow in progress

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I know this question is duplicate but please give some solution please. Android FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime() is slow in progress, my fragment take almost 10 second to generate the video frames

Answer (score 0):

According to [Android ANR Multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33711153/android-anr-multithreading), switching from `FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever` to `MediaMetadataRetriever` sounds like it should fix your problem.

In the future, please dig a little bit more (or mention if you've tried a posted answer that didn't work) before asking a question! It is also good practice to provide information about what environment you're using; what version of Android is this? In what context are you having issues? That information can help avoid confusion.

Finally, your post does not clearly state what solution you were hoping for. While I'm sure most people could figure it out, it's always good to be explicit when asking what you need. Hope the linked answer helped you out :)

Comment: SwarthyMantooth thank you for your suggestion and sorry for the incomplete information. In my app i record a video using CameraView library, after the video recording i want to get the all frames of videos like instagram. That's why i use FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever, it works and i recieve frames list. The only problem is it take almost 10 to 12 second to produce the frames. I'm using Android Studio 3.5 (AndroidX) and FFmpeg version is 1.0.14.

Comment: for (int i=1000000; i<= timeInMillisec*1000; i+=1000000){
                bitmap = fFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(i, FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
                bitmaps_array.add(bitmap);
            }

Comment: Can you add that info to the original post through an edit? It will help others who see the question give you an answer more quickly